# Visual Studio Enterprise Version 15.9 causing issues with ASP.NET Core 2.1 API project?

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.1

Working on an ASP.NET Core 2.1 project with some of my team members.

I was running VS Enterprise 15.9 and when I ran the project locally via IIEXpress, any pages would say cannot load the page.  Looking at trace logs in IISExpress directory, it would say Bad Gateway.

Did a lot of searching for issues (port already in use, permission issues, etc) and nothing seem to work.

I did notice that the two developers having the issue (myself and someone else) both had VS 15.9 and others were on VS 15.8.8.

I reverted down to 15.8.9 and sure enough, the project ran and I was able to access the Swagger page.

We are not sure if 15.9 had some kind of compatibility with something in our project.  We would hate to say don't install 15.9.

Anyone have any ideas what to check?  I'm installing 15.9 on a VM so I have a sandbox to figure out why 15.8.9 works and 15.9 doesn't.

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that we could work with?

Comment: 15.9.5 is already out. Make sure you test the latest and on a clean machine. VS upgrade can fail miserably sometimes.

Comment: Sorry, I do have 15.9.5.  Also, installed everything fresh on a VM to rule out a bad upgrade and have the same issue.  On my local machine, downgraded to 15.8.9 and it runs as expected.

Comment: @bdd sounds like a tooling issue, you should probably report it: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues

Comment: @IanKemp Thank.  Ya, a co-worker found it had to do with the .NETCore version.  He found a version that worked with all versions of VS that we are using. 2.1.4 I think.  Surprised others in the community haven't already posted about this.